# Flutter: Problem When Using CheckboxListTile() with Positioned() while in a Stack() Scenario

Tags: flutter, layout

I'm unable to position a **CheckboxListTile()** widget (using **Positioned()**) where the widget is one of the children of a **Stack()** parent widget. The widget is not appearing on the screen, as if either it is hidden behind another widget, or it is being rendered out of its designated client area.

Here is the code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Stack(
      
      children: [
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: CheckboxListTile(
              value: checkboxImage,
              title: Text(widget.label),
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => checkboxImage = value),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
          ),
        ),
      ],

    );
  }
```

Here is what I've tried:

- I've already omitted all the other sibling widgets in the stack to rule out the possibility that the CheckboxListTile() is being hidden behind other sibling widgets.
- If I replace the CheckboxListTile() widget, with a simple widget like Text('Hello'), that widget will appear.
- If I omit the Positioned() widget and just replace it with the CheckboxListTile() widget, the widget will appear.
- There is no effect if I pass other coordinates to Positioned() ie- Positioned(left:10, top: 20), or Positioned(left:10, top: -10).
- I looked at the widget in Dart Devtools, and the Positioned() widget along with its CheckboxListTile() child is appearing in the widget tree but that's as far as I got as the devtools version I was using cannot show Positioned() widget in the layout pane.

All help / suggestions greatly appreciated.

/Joselito

Answer (score 1):

My IDE gives me a `BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.` error if i omit `right: 0`.

```
 Positioned(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            child: ...
)
```

Comment: Pingyang, thank you very much. Adding the right:0 property did the trick!

Now to understand why this works, judging your post, that without the right:0 property, an unbounded constraint is imposed on the child, in this case ChecklistBoxTile(), which caused it to be rendered in an area where it is not visible? If so, I'm confused cuz when I've got a widget that tries to be as big as possible and then it receives an unbounded constraint, the app usually throws an exception which its not doing in this case. It's just not visible. But it with your suggestion, it works, so I thank you!